# Right to left support for Apple Numbers app

Tags: right-to-left, apple-numbers

How can i create a sheet in Numbers app with right to left supports (Header columns on the right , Freeze columns on the right ...) ?

I tried to import Excel file with RTL sheet but it was inverted to LTR by the app.

Please don't suggest to use other app like Excel or some open source app, I want to use Numbers app.

I use Mac Numbers ver 3.6.2 (13 May 2016).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple added "Table direction" to table settings so now I can use RTL tables.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you want to create a new spreadsheet, there is an option to select your language ( which you've selected for input source ), You can select your RTL language other than English and it automatically creates a spreadsheet in right side of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that without changing the language of the OS to Arabic, which will change everything from LTR to RTL. In addition to that all dates and numbers will be shown in Arabic in Numbers app as well as the other built-in apps.